# Numpy indexing when splitting dataset randomly

Tags: numpy

I am learning how to use numpy through their documentation and came across this example where I don't understand the indexing: iris_X[indices[:-10]]

I would like to ask what the indices[:-10] does or even the [:-10]. I looked at their docs on indexing but no clearer on the matter.

This is the entire last part of the program that will provide more context.

```
# Split iris data in train and test data
>>> # A random permutation, to split the data randomly
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> indices = np.random.permutation(len(iris_X))
>>> iris_X_train = iris_X[indices[:-10]]
>>> iris_y_train = iris_y[indices[:-10]]
>>> iris_X_test = iris_X[indices[-10:]]
>>> iris_y_test = iris_y[indices[-10:]]
>>> # Create and fit a nearest-neighbor classifier
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
>>> knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
>>> knn.fit(iris_X_grain) 
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
           weights='uniform')
>>> knn.predict(iris_X_test)
array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
>>> iris_y_test
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
```

Thanks so much for any help.I think its an important concept.

Comment: It's specifically written in their [indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html). "Negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end of the array" and "Negative `i` and `j` are interpreted as `n + i` and `n + j` where n is the number of elements in the corresponding dimension. Negative `k` makes stepping go towards smaller indices."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indices[:-10]` means "from beginning to tenth counting from the back". Look at this example

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
print(a[:-2])

[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```